# How to get the document body content after an event has been operating (WebBrowser Control)

Tags: c#, class, events, operation

how to get the **DocResult** after **_web_ProgressChanged** has been operating?

```
public class WebHelper
{
    WebBrowser _web = null;

    public string DocResult = string.Empty;
    public WebHelper(string url)
    {
        _web = new WebBrowser();
        _web.ProgressChanged += _web_ProgressChanged;
        _web.Navigate(url);
    }

    void _web_ProgressChanged(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DocResult = _web.Document.Body.InnerHtml;
    }
}
class MyWork
{
    public string GetDocContent(string url)
    {
        WebHelper wh = new WebHelper(url);
        return wh.DocResult;
    }
}
```

how to get the **DocResult** after **_web_ProgressChanged** has been operating?

Answer (score 2):

> how to get the DocResult after _web_ProgressChanged has been operating?

You don't.  ProgressChanged stopped being useful to give any feedback at least a decade ago.  It still made somewhat sense back in the 1990s when browsers were connected to the Internet service provider through a low-speed telephone modem.  And web pages were still very stark, very little markup and styling, so the user didn't have to wait for *minutes* for a web page to load.  ProgressChanged was useful then to drive a progress bar to indicate how much longer he had to wait.

That's over and done with, web pages today are built up with *many* data transfers.  Easily a dozen or more, totaling hundreds of kilobytes.  Some transferring data from the web server itself, some from a CDN, some from a 3rd party server for things like analytics.  Some are html, some are css, some are javascript, some are images.  Each tickling ProgressChanged, it wildly changes while a web page is busy loading.  Browsers don't show progress anymore, just a spinner.

There is no connection between the ProgressChanged event and the state of the DOM, there never was one.  You **must** use the DocumentCompleted event before attempting to use the `Document` property.

Comment: You do not understand the meaning of the operations in this code. And I understand the meaning of what you have said. But I just need to get the content after the event is done. 

You can see this example and you will understand what I mean.

[DemoWebHelper Project](https://mega.co.nz/#!T543XZAD!YnHrbNiGqaAAoLvq14_94XoPZNl3ahFg8X-SMyA5t74)

Comment: Thank @Hans Passant. I have found how fixed it with 
'while (_wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {   
                Application.DoEvents();
            }'

Comment: That is [a bug, not a fix](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5183623/17034).  Use the DocumentCompleted event.

Comment: Are you sure using class WebHelper to get DocResult and insert it into rtbOther control. I have changed event ProgressChanged to DocumentComplete but DocResult is empty. If you Navigate an search uri(http://google.com.vn/#q=some+keywork) from webBrowser control with event DocumentComplete do not get a list search result for you.  It is get document of google home page. Events Navigated, DocumentComplete, ProgressChanged - only after ProgressChanged event is done...it is get list search result from google to you.